# Excel VBA: Locking range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to lock a few ranges of cells to prevent them from being altered outside of the button press.
I have the following code so far:

```
Private Sub DateRangePayer()

Dim unionRange As Range, uRng As Range, EssentialWrite As Range, chCell As Range, chRng As Range
Dim d As Long, k As Long, x As Long

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Set EssentialWrite = Sheets("Essential Info").Range("E2:E6")
Set unionRange = ActiveSheet.Range("Q8:R12, T8:T12, Q16:R20, T16:T20")
Set chRng = ActiveSheet.Range("Q8:R12, T8:T12, Q16:R20, T16:T20")

x = Sheets("Essential Info").Range("G19").Value
ReDim OArr(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Variant

For d = DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x), 1) To DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x) + 1, 0) - 1
    If Weekday(d, vbSunday) = 7 Then
        k = k + 1
        OArr(k, 1) = d
    End If
Next d

If k = 4 Then OArr(k + 1, 1) = "-"

For Each uRng In unionRange.Areas
    uRng.Value = OArr
    uRng.NumberFormat = "dd-mmmm"
Next uRng

For Each chCell In chRng.Cells
    chCell.MergeArea.Locked = (chCell.Value <> "")
Next chCell

EssentialWrite.Value = OArr
EssentialWrite.NumberFormat = "dd-mmmm"

ActiveSheet.Protect


End Sub
```

The main parts of the code are the

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect


For Each chCell In chRng.Cells
chCell.MergeArea.Locked = (chCell.Value <> "") Next chCell


ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Currently the code executes with zero errors. However the range of cells is not locked at all and is actually editable in its entirety.
Im doing this to prevent unexpected user entries in the specified cells
Any advice on what may work.

Im sorry if the code is a little messy. Im kinda just hacking together at this point and relatively new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code locks only the code that say LOCKED in the image below.

```
Sub lockCells()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Cells.Locked = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Locked = cell.Value <> ""
    Next cell

    ws.Protect 1234
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Its protecting the entire sheet with the password attached now. So thats one step further, just need to narrow it down to the specified cells

Comment: Nothing now :/ Am i setting ws.Cells.Locked = True at the end of the loop?

Comment: not really sure what you are looking to do. lock only certain cells in a range correct? see edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is 'best practice' but I'd use:

```
chCell.Cells(1, 1).Locked = (chCell.Value <> "")
```

Comment: Would this not do the same thing as the range though? Instead of the range, youre just defining the row/column address?

Comment: No. I'm specifying the first cell in each 'area'.  It worked for me in testing.